# Drag drop text into notepad

Tags: notepad

I want to copy and insert a text through drag and drop from a browser or text editors like UltraEdit or Notepad++. When I drag the text over Windows 7 notepad, it is not accepting the selected text. Does Windows 7 notepad accept any other types other than a File types?

Comment: Sorry Lerner, your post is very hard to understand. Are you trying to drag and drop a file into notepad, or are you trying to drag and drop some text?

Comment: Trying to drag and drop some text. Just wanna know what types can be dropped into notepad other than Files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to "drag and drop" text then just copy and paste it into notepad instead of trying to drag and drop it.